# Unable to parse URL parameters in Flask

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have deployed a Flask application using Apache on a CentOS VPS. Here is the link I followed to deploy my app: https://medium.com/@mohdejazsiddiqui/deploy-flask-app-in-apache-shared-hosting-5b3c82c8fd5e. For some strange reason my Flask app is unable to detect url parameters which is working perfectly in my local environment. I have raised this already to my VPS provider but I just want to check if anybody here have the same experience.

Sample url: `mydomain.net/login?error=error_message`
Here is my code:

```
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, request, url_for, render_template
import requests

from myapp.forms import Login, Signup

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__) #This is imported in the main view

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def login():
    loginform = Login()
    signupform = Signup()

    ...
    current_url = request.url
    err = request.args.get('error', '')
    ...

    return something
```

When I print out `current_url` it only returns my base url `mydomain.net`, and err is an empty string. I have also tried `request.form` to no avail.

Here is my `.htaccess` file just in case if this is an apache related issue:

```
# .htaccess
Options +ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script .py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/servername/public_html/mydomain.net/app.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
            from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for
            @app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
            def login():    
                return "Hello World!"
                # return render_template('/auth/login.html')

            @app.route('/auth/login',methods=['POST'])
            def post_login():
                error = None
                email = request.form.get('email')
                password = request.form.get('password')

                if email!='nandhini@gmail.com' or password !='nandhini':
                    error="invalid email and password"
                    return render_template('/auth/login.html',error=error, email=email,password=password)
                else:
                    flash('you were successfully logged in','success')
                    return redirect(url_for('register'))
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem.